# VS for Mac can't open any files: "The file ... could not be opened"

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I can't open up any files in Visual Studio 2019 for Mac.

`.json`, `.cs`, `.fs`, and `.config` files all fail with a message that looks similar to the following:

[image]

This is on a fresh install. It occurs even on a brand new console project created in VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to uninstall and reinstall VS. It took ~30minutes, but it worked.